# Python encryption and rotation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Could you please help with the following code. I am trying to write a function def encrypt(text, rot), which will receive input as a string and integer. My function should result of rotating each letter in the text by no of rotations to the right. For example my output should be like this:`The final outcome is like

```
Enter a message:
Hello!
Rotate by:
5
Mjqqt
```

!

This is the code:

```
    def encrypt(text, rot):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    encrypted = ''
    for char in text, rot:
        if char == ' ':
            encrypted = encrypted + ' '
        else:
            rotated_index = alphabet.index(char) + 5
            if rotated_index < 26:
                encrypted = encrypted + alphabet[rotated_index]
            else:
                encrypted = encrypted + alphabet[rotated_index % 26]
    return encrypted

print(rot5('abcde'))
```

Could you please help with the above following code. This should generate the following ouput:  Enter a message:
    Hello!
    Rotate by:
    5
    Mjqqt

---

Thank you. I did correct this, but the problem is when I change hello to Hello, World it is giving me an error.

```
def encrypt(text, rot):
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
encrypted = ''
for char in text:
    if char == ' ':
        encrypted = encrypted + ' '
    else:
        rotated_index = alphabet.index(char) + rot
        if rotated_index < 26:
            encrypted = encrypted + alphabet[rotated_index]
        else:
            encrypted = encrypted + alphabet[rotated_index % 26]
return encrypted

print(encrypt('Hello, World', 5))
```

Comment: What seems to be the issue with it?

Comment: @vist Shouldn't `print(rot5('abcde'))` be `print(encrypt('abcde', 5))`?

Comment: @vist Change `print(rot5('abcde'))` to `print(encrypt('abcde', 5))` and `for char in text, rot:` to `for char in text` and the code seems to work fine. The output for this call is `fghij`.

Comment: Thank you. I did correct this, I am getting an error if I add Hello, World. Could you please check it

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to check if the index is less than 26. Because the `%` operator returns the dividend when the dividend is less than the divisor (26) and the remainder when the dividend is greater than or equal to the divisor.

```
def rotate(s, n):
    from string import ascii_letters as letters
    length = len(letters)
    for char in s:
        index = (letters.find(char) + n) % length
        yield letters[index]

 ''.join(rot('Hello', 5))
'Mjqqt'
```